# T-SQL String to DateTime-conversion

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to cast string values of the following formats to DateTime:

```
2042-04
2011-01
```

Is there an easy way to do this? I've tried `CAST` AND `CONVERT` without much luck.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try appending "-01" to the end of it and then doing the cast or convert

Answer (score 2):

```
declare @S varchar(7)
set @S = '2042-04'

select cast(stuff(@S, 5, 1, '')+'01' as datetime)
```

YYYYMMDD is a safe format regardless of [SET DATEFORMAT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx). YYYY-MM-DD is not. http://www.sommarskog.se/wishlist.html#YYYYMMDD

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CAST('2011-01-01' AS DATETIME)
SELECT CONVERT(DATE , '2011-01-01')
```

It seems you need to add a 'day' to the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @Table Table
(
    ColDateTime Varchar(100)
)
Insert into @Table
Select '2042-04' UNION ALL
Select '2011-01'

Select ColDateTime As VarcharCol,
Cast(
    substring(ColDateTime,0,charindex('-',ColDateTime))+substring(ColDateTime,charindex('-',ColDateTime)+1,len(ColDateTime))+'01'
As DateTime) As DateTimeCol
from @Table
```